# Unable to change Beautify indent size

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to change the indent size for CSS/SCSS to two spaces in Atom Beautify, but it has no effect and the indent remains at four spaces. Even if I set it to two spaces in my .jsbeautifyrc file, it has no effect. Am I missing something?

```
{
    "indent_size": 2,
    "indent_char": " ",
    "indent_level": 0,
    "indent_with_tabs": false,
    "preserve_newlines": true,
    "max_preserve_newlines": 10,
    "jslint_happy": false,
    "space_after_anon_function": false,
    "brace_style": "collapse-preserve-inline",
    "keep_array_indentation": false,
    "keep_function_indentation": false,
    "space_before_conditional": true,
    "break_chained_methods": false,
    "eval_code": false,
    "unescape_strings": false,
    "wrap_line_length": 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`atom-beautify` uses its own configuration, which can be changed in the following two ways in Atom:

1. In the Settings GUI

   - `Ctrl` + `,` to open Settings (or File > Settings)
   - Select **Packages**
   - Find `atom-beautify` and click on **Settings**
   - Find **CSS** and click to expand the Settings for CSS
   - Enter your desired indent size where it says **Indent Size:**
   - Repeat previous 2 steps for **SCSS**
2. In `config.cson`

   - File > Config... to open `config.cson`
   - Add the following
3. ```
   "atom-beautify":
     css:
       indent_size: 2
     scss:
       indent_size: 2
   ```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but the indent size is already set to two in both of these places, which is why I don't understand why it doesn't format my code as expected.

Comment: Something that might help is to use the debug feature of Atom Beautify.

`Command Palette` -> `Atom Beautify: Help Debug Editor`. This creates a huge output file, but it might help in pinpointing where the indent settings are being read from.

Comment: Also, it's possible to use https://github.com/harmsk/atomic-management to have a per-project config.